# For loop is adding an extra value/element

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

[Here is the sample dataframe.](https://github.com/rileydlynch/testnotes/blob/master/testnotes.csv)

I have a function which uses a for loop to go through a dataframe for a specified number of columns, remove NA values, remove duplicate values, then return the length of the final vector which has all the unique values present in the specified columns. The columns represent time, and the goal is to show how many total unique values have existed up until a certain point in time. Here's the sample matrix:

```
    X1   X2   X3 X4 X5   X6
1    F    F    F  F  F    F
2    C    C    C  C  C    C
3    D    D    D  D  D    D
4   A#   A#   A#  A  A    A
5 <NA> <NA> <NA>  G  G <NA>
```

And here's the function:

```
uniquepitches <- function(file, col){
  y <- read.csv(file, na.strings=c(""))
  frame <- data.frame(y)
  x <- c()

  for(i in 1:col) {
    noNAframe <- frame[!is.na(frame[, 1:i])]
    x[i] <- length(unique(noNAframe))
  }
  x
}
```

The issue is that when I run it for any value for `col`, I get the wrong values. For example, `uniquepitches("testnotes.csv", 1)` gives me `5`, which should be `4`. `uniquepitches("testnotes.csv", 6)` gives me `[1] 5 5 5 6 6 6`, which should be `[1] 4 4 4 6 6 6`. So as of right now it looks like the x vector has one element too many in the first three run-throughs, which is why the length is one too many. How can I fix it so that it's the correct length?

Comment: Could you include the sample csv to the question?

Comment: Your desired answer should be `4 4 4 6 6 6`, no? You have two new chords in row `X4`, A and G. Try this instead of what you have: `noNAframe <- as.vector(dat[,1:i])`and `x[i] <- length(unique(noNAframe[!is.na(noNAframe)]))`. @bgoldst solution is definetly more elegant though.

Comment: @Molx yes you are right, I put the wrong numbers, it should be 4 4 4 6 6 6.

Comment: @TavoloPerUno I just added it to Github, link is at the very beginning of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task can be accomplished with `sapply()`:

```
df <- data.frame(X1=c('F','C','D','A#',NA), X2=c('F','C','D','A#',NA), X3=c('F','C','D','A#',NA), X4=c('F','C','D','A','G'), X5=c('F','C','D','A','G'), X6=c('F','C','D','A',NA) );
sapply(df, function(c) length(unique(c[!is.na(c)])) );
## X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
##  4  4  4  5  5  4
```

**Edit:** @Molx might be correct, although the OP needs to clarify to be sure. If the requirement is indeed to process the cumulative column content, rather than each individual column in isolation, then you can do this:

```
sapply(1:ncol(df), function(c) length(unique(df[,1:c][!is.na(df[,1:c])])) );
## [1] 4 4 4 6 6 6
```

**Edit:** Sorry, I should've been clearer. The `sapply()` call *replaces* the entire for loop. So the function can be rewritten as follows:

```
uniquepitches <- function(file,col) {
    frame <- read.csv(file,na.strings=c(""));
    sapply(1:col, function(c) length(unique(frame[,1:c][!is.na(frame[,1:c])])) );
}
```

(Also notice that [`read.csv()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) returns a data.frame, so there's no need for manual coercion.)

Comment: This is a better idea, but it's not exactly what he needs. He wants the accumulated unique pitches, that would be `4 4 4 5 5 5` with your data (which is a bit different from his example dataframe).

Comment: @Molx, I've fixed my data.frame to correspond to his example data.frame; I had assumed the hashes were incorrect, but I suppose that was an improper assumption.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but then I realized it's music info. I think your answer is perfect now, might look complicated but it's a one-liner.

Comment: I'm still getting errors when I run your code, `sapply(1:ncol...` If I run it in the console by itself, I get `Error in lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : attempt to apply non-function`, and if I run within the function I get `Warning message:
In 1:col(frame) : numerical expression has 30 elements: only the first used`.

Comment: Well, I can diagnose the warning message: `1:col(frame)` should be `1:ncol(frame)`. The error `attempt to apply non-function` is thrown by R when you try to call a non-function as a function, e.g. `3.141();`. You must've changed the second argument of `sapply()` in such a way that causes it to fail in this way. I can't be more precise without seeing the actual code.

Comment: So I've run this:

`uniquepitches <- function(file, col){
  y <- read.csv(file, na.strings=c(""))
  frame <- data.frame(y)
  for(i in 1:col){
  x <- sapply(1:ncol(frame), function(c) length(unique(frame[,i][!is.na(frame[,i])])) )
  }
  x
}` and then `uniquepitches("testnotes.csv", 3)' in the console, but unfortunately this just gives me `[1] 4 4 4 4 4 4'

Comment: It looks to be working! I'll test it out on a larger dataframe for an entire composition later to make sure. Thanks for the help!